# Deserializing Nested Kafka JSON to a simple POJO for Flink usage

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm currently getting JSON looking like that from my kafka source :

```
{
    "url": "/import/something",
    "body": {
        "user_id": "4110e4f5-09d6-45d1-806a-fbe311f7fa17",
        "session_id": "8819a20b-1b19-4563-86a5-66c063e0e10d",
        "media_id": "11fb4e1a-9bb9-4b3c-90a3-c1cb2152b035",
        "timestamp": "2023-12-31T19:17:43Z"
    },
    "headers": {
        "host": "something.com",
        "x-request-id": "041117da2717b5a3a1809ec342f855be",
        "x-real-ip": "199.22.29.9",
        "x-forwarded-for": "199.22.29.9"
    }
}
```

My goal is to deserialize them to a simple POJO so I can, for example, simply filter them according to the URL addresse for example.

Following the official documentation about JSON : https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/json/

I declared the JsonDeserializationSchema and my kafka source :

```
JsonDeserializationSchema<VodMessage> jsonFormat =new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(VodMessage.class);

        //...

        KafkaSource<VodMessage> source = KafkaSource
                .<VodMessage>builder()
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(jsonFormat)
                .build();
```

I keep having the following error :

`Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type` java.lang.String`from Object value (token`JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)`

Googling around, it seems that the problem is due to the nested parts of the Json ( "body" : {}, "headers" : {}).

I was wondering if you could help me understand what I did wrong or how to solve this current issue.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't think this is a Flink issue - sounds like a JSON deserialization problem. A quick search got me to https://www.baeldung.com/jsonmappingexception-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-from-object-value-token-jsontoken-start_object

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in front of my eyes.
I simply had forgotten to declare the nested properties inside a child class within the main POJO. Doing so fixed my deserialization issue.